# Problems with authorization via Requests

Tags: python

```
import requests

url = "https://qlinkwireless.com/members/Login.aspx"
profile = 'https://qlinkwireless.com/customer/members/plans'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
data = {
    'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MainContent$login': u'email',
    'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MainContent$password': u'password'
}

def check_auth():
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    profile_response = session.get(profile)

    print(profile_response.text)
check_auth()
```

When the program is authorized, it should follow the link and display its code, but in the end I get a completely different page and code

You can try it yourself, even if you enter the wrong username or password

The problem is that it always gives **status_code 200**, even if the login or password are incorrect

[Link to site with authorization](https://qlinkwireless.com/members/Login.aspx)

Comment: The website returns a fully server-side rendered HTML (so far 200 seems ok).

Comment: Have you tried manually logging in on that site and seeing what happens? `requests` will be doing exactly what would happen if you did that. You'll need your script to take into account how the website deals with incorrect logins. Best way would be to look for any auth cookies that may have been set.

Comment: This is not a webservice, but a normal web page. 1. Web page sites return normally status 200 or 302 when authentication is not successful. 2. Web sites use sessions, so you'll need to do a first request to get the session cookie, and send this with your request. 3. Often, tokens will be used (CSRF token , etc.) to avoid attacks. In the simplest case, you will have to send the token gotten from the login page, but often it's not that simple.

Comment: I have never seen a `u` used before in a string since python 3 assumes that all strings are unicode...  interesting as to why the OP uses this ?